# How do I allow my ASP.NET Core tag helpers to be self-closing

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have written a tag helper that I can use as follows...

```
<mytaghelper attr1="jim"></mytaghelper>
```

I would like to be able to shorten this to just...

```
<mytaghelper attr1="jim">
```

...or at least...

```
<mytaghelper attr1="jim"/>
```

However, I can't get this to work. Here is some sample code for the Process method...

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output) {
  output.TagName = "div";
  output.PreContent.SetHtmlContent("<div>");
  output.Content.SetHtmlContent("OUTPUT HTML GOES HERE");
  output.PostContent.SetHtmlContent("</div>");
  output.Attributes.Clear();
}
```

I have tried adding a `TagStructure` setting to the `HtmlTargetElement` attribute on the class...

```
[HtmlTargetElement("mytaghelper", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
```

...but it doesn't seem to make any difference. `<mytaghelper attr1="jim"/>` generates `<div />` and `<mytaghelper attr1="jim"></mytaghelper>` generates `<div></mytaghelper>`.

If I set the `TagStructure` to `NormalOrSelfClosing` then included a closing tag works, but `<mytaghelper attr1="jim"/>` gives an empty `<div />`

Anyone able to explain what I need to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`TagStructure.WithoutEndTag` is able to write the tag with only a start tag or self-closing, but the output would be `<div >` or `<div/>` . Self-closing anchor tags are not valid HTML, so you wouldn't want to create one, but you might want to create a tag helper that's self-closing. Tag helpers set the type of the [TagMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.language.tagmode?view=aspnetcore-2.2) property after reading a tag. Add the below code line Inside the process method:

```
output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
```

Take a moment to read [Author Tag Helpers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.2) which covers this perfectly .

Comment: I have no idea what you mean about anchor tags, as I never mentioned them at all. However, the `TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag` did what I needed. Thanks for the link, it was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("mytaghelper", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
```

Which should be applied to the taghelper *class*, not the `Process` method. You may already be doing that, but it wasn't clear in your question. I believe you still must use the self-closing tag syntax (`/>`) for it work, though.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I did add the attribute to the class, and tried the option you showed, but it didn't work. Please see my updated question, where I (hopefully) clarified it, and showed what happens with both styles of tag. Thanks